# Weird NSNumber allocation expression

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsnumber

Consider the following `NSNumber` instances:

```
NSNumber *b1 = @((long)(-61));
NSNumber *b2 = @((long)(-62));

NSLog(@"%@", b1);
NSLog(@"%@", b2);
```

The “Variables View” within the “Debug Area” shows curious values:

[image]

Does someone has any idea about this debugger infomation?

Answer (score 1):

`0xffffffffffffffc3` is the hex representation of `-61`.
`0x00ffffffffffffc3` is the hex representation of `72057594037927875`.

The “Variables View” within the “Debug Area” simply has troubles correctly representing negative `long` values of a `NSNumber`.

[image]

What’s ironic is that if you use an `unsigned long` for the underlying value for the `NSNumber` (see `value4`/`b4` in above screen snapshot), the variables view will now show it as `-61`.

But, this is just a bug in the display of the `NSNumber` instances in the “Variables View”. The actual `NSNumber` values are fine.